# How to convert the column header to a whole diffrent column

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I have a excel file in which contains columns of value of current for diffrent configuration in the first column there is voltage but other parameters are in columnheader itself. How do i convert those column header to a diffrent column

**input**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'V1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 
         'I(T=27 v2=5)': [4, 5, 4, 8], 
         'I(T=140 v2=5)': [5, 9, 4, 12]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

[image]

**desired output**

[image]

Comment: We need text-based examples to provide answers. This time I created one for you, but please read the following post and provide text-based examples from next time. :
[why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
tmp1 = df.melt('V1', value_name='I')
pat = r'^I\(T=(?P<T>\d+) v2=(?P<V2>\d+)\)$'
tmp2 = tmp1.pop('variable').str.extract(pat).astype('int')
out = pd.concat([tmp1, tmp2], axis=1)[['V1', 'T', 'V2', 'I']]
```

out

```
    V1  T   V2  I
0   1   27  5   4
1   2   27  5   5
2   3   27  5   4
3   4   27  5   8
4   1   140 5   5
5   2   140 5   9
6   3   140 5   4
7   4   140 5   12
```

Comment: The  pat thing is not working it return NaN values

Comment: @PiyushGoenka I have created sample code in your main text. Please run the provided sample and then run the code in the response. This is another reason why a code-based example is especially necessary. If the examples in the main text work, but they don't work on your dataset, the reason becomes clear.

Comment: here you made a dataframe by using a set of data but i have a csv file. so i am using pd.read_csv to create the dataframe

Comment: @PiyushGoenka If  code works on the example I provided, then it means answer is correct. On the other hand, if it doesn't work on your dataset, it means that your dataset is different from the example in the text. If you receive answer with an example that doesn't apply to your dataset and you are told that it doesn't work, how can we solve the problem?

Comment: ok i found the problem you did not include the "I" in the 2nd and 3rd columns. Also one last question what is the temp is in negative.

Comment: @PiyushGoenka edit pattern for negative value `pat = r'^I\(T=(?P<T>\-*\d+) v2=(?P<V2>\-*\d+)\)$'`